# Proving that for certain ring of algebraic integers $R$, $R/bR$ is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

This is a part of proof I try to understand.

The situation is the following:

Suppose that $a,b,x,y$ are algebraic integers  such that $b \neq 0$ and $ax+by=1$. Set $K:=\mathbb{Q}(a,b,x,y)$ and $R:=O_K,$ that is, a subring of all algebraic integers contained in $K$.

Next statement of the proof is (whithout any further comments):

"Then $R/bR$ is a finite ring."

Hence my question:

**How can I prove that $R/bR$ is finite? Or is it somewhat obvious?**

(I should probably add that my knowledge of alg. number theory is *very* limited.)

My attempt so far:

From the given relation, it is not difficult to see that every element of $R/bR$ can be expressed as a $\mathbb{Q}-$linear combination of elements of the type $a^jy^i+bR$, $x^jy^i+bR$ for some $i,j \leq N$, where $N$ is a sufficiently large integer. I would also guess that there are not many possibilities for the values of the rational coefficients in those linear combinations. But that seems to be far from the desired conclusion.

Comment: where did this proof come from?

Comment: Isn't it true that if $K$ is any number field (finite extension of the rationals), and $R$ is the ring of integers of $K$, and $b\ne0$ is in $R$, then $R/bR$ is a finite ring?

Comment: @chris: It is the proof that every (complex) algebraic number can be expressed as $u+\frac{1}{v}$ for suitable algebraic integers $u,v$. I am sure that I have not left out any further assumptions, though.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: I do not know, as I said, I don't know much about alg. number theory. However, I suspected it might be something well-known. Can you, please, provide some reference? That would be most helpful.

Comment: I agree with @GerryMyerson, more generally: $$|R/bR|=N_{K/\mathbb Q}(b)$$where the latter is the _field norm_.

Comment: Pretty much any intro Algebraic Number Theory text should do. Stewart and Tall, for one.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a general thing about rings of integers, it has nothing to do with your problem...

Let $K$ be any number field, and $R$ its ring of integers. Then you can check that $R$ is free as a $\mathbb Z$-module, in particular $R \simeq \mathbb Z^n$ where $n$ is the degree of $K$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Therefore if you have any integer $N \in \mathbb Z$, then $R / N R $ is clearly finite (it has cardinality $N^n$!).

Now let $b \in R$, so that $b$ satisfies a monic polynomial equation with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$:
$$ b^n + a_{n-1}b^{n-1} + \dots + a_0 = 0$$
of minimal degree. In particular, $a_0 \neq 0$, and 
$$ a_0 = - a_1 b - a_2 b^2 - \dots - b^n = b ( -a_1 - a_2 b - \dots - b^{n-1}) \in b R,$$
i.e., $a_0 R \subseteq bR$.

So $|R / bR | \leq |R / a_0R|$, and this last ring is finite as we showed above.

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove the following theorem:

> **Theorem**
>   In a finite algebraic extension $K/\mathbb Q$ with the ring of integers $R$, if $p\in R$, then $\mid R/pR\mid=\text{N}_{K/\mathbb Q}(p)$.

We shall prove this by use of the following two lemmas:

> **Lemma I** (Chinese Remainder Theorem)
>   If an ideal $\mathfrak A=\mathfrak B\mathfrak  C$ in a ring $R$, and if $\mathfrak B+\mathfrak C=R$, then $R/\mathfrak A\cong R/\mathfrak B\oplus R/\mathfrak C$.

**Proof**
Define $\phi: R/\mathfrak A\rightarrow R/\mathfrak B\oplus R/\mathfrak C$ by sending $x+\mathfrak A$ to $(x+\mathfrak B,x+\mathfrak C)$. Then by assumption, there are $b\in \mathfrak B, c\in\mathfrak C$ such that $b+c=1$. And we define $\psi:R/\mathfrak B\oplus R/\mathfrak C\rightarrow R/\mathfrak A$ by sending $(x+\mathfrak B,y+\mathfrak C)$ to $(xc+yb)+\mathfrak A$. Clearly $\psi$ is the inverse of $\phi$, hence the conclusion.

> **Lemma II**
>   It is our theorem, in the case of prime $\mathfrak p\in R$.

**Proof**
Since $\mathfrak p$ is prime, the ideal $\mathfrak pR$ is maximal, as $R$ is a Dedekind domain. And for $\mathfrak pR\cap \mathbb Z$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb Z$, it is generated by a prime integer $p\in\mathbb Z$. Now $\kappa=R/\mathfrak pR$ is a finite extension of the finite field $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, so $\kappa$ is also a finite field, with its degree of extension $=f$. Then we should prove that $\text{N}(\mathfrak p)=p^f=\mid R/\mathfrak pR\mid$. (Up to this point, the desired finiteness has been proved, without using the lemmas at all.)
Now let $L/K$ be a normal closure of $K$, and let $[L:K]=m, [K:\mathbb Q]=n$. Let $(p)=\prod_{i=1}^k\mathfrak P_i^{e_i}$ be the prime ideal factorisation of $(p)=pR'$, where $R'$ is the ring of integers of $L$, and where $\mathfrak P_1=(\mathfrak p)$. Since $L/\mathbb Q$ is galois, all the ramification indices $e_i$ are equal, denoted by $e$. Further, all the $p^{f_i}=\mid R'/\mathfrak P_i\mid$ are equal to some $p^{f'}$. So we have $ef'k=nm$, by means of lemma I, and of the isomorphism $R/\mathfrak P\cong \mathfrak P/\mathfrak P^2$.
Now $\text{N}_{L/\mathbb Q}\mathfrak P_1=\prod_{i=1}^k\mathfrak P_i^{nm/k}=\prod_{i=1}^k\mathfrak P_i^{ef'}=(p)^{f'}$. Writing $f''=[R'/\mathfrak P_1:R/\mathfrak p]$, we find: $f'=ff''$. Thus, from $\text{N}_{K/\mathbb Q}\circ\text{N}_{L/K}=\text{N}_{L/\mathbb Q}$, we obtain the claim.

> **Proof of the theorem**
>   First we observe that the norm of $p$ is equal to the norm of the ideal $pR$ generated by $p$. Then this ideal can be written as a product of prime ideals. By the above two lemmas, we obtain the theorem as an immediate consequence.  **Q.E.D**

If something does not pertain here, tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YACP The first point is my bad; I stated wrongly the conditions. And the second point is a typo, which has been fixed now. Thanks very much for pointing them out.